# Cant change the header title to InputText?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to change the header title to TextInput, however, I get nothing. I am trying to do something like this

```
setHeader(){
    this.props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: <TextInput style={styles.searchInput}/>
    });
  }
```

If i change TextInput to just Text, then it works. However, I want TextInput

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**
I noticed this works but it dismiss the keyboard every time i type.

```
<SearchStack.Screen 
      name = "Search" component = {Search}
      options={{
       title: <TextInput placeholder="hiasdfadsf"/>,
      cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forScaleFromCenterAndroid,
      headerBackTitleVisible: false , headerTintColor: "black"}} />
```

I'm wondering why this works but it doesn't work when using setOptions?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `<Text>` in the `headerTitle` in navigationOptions. By default it does not accept any other element.

You can use `header` option and create your own header where you can use `<TextInput/>`

Example:

```
     this.props.navigation.setOptions = () =>
           return {
              header: (
              <View style={{width: '100%', height: 60}}>
                 <TextInput style={styles.searchInput}/>
              </View>
              )
            }
        };
```

Comment: But I noticed you can set TextInput as title I updated my code.

Comment: Updated answer @JamesLee. Try this and let me know if it works

Comment: i get "options.header is not a function". However, i replaced header with headerTile and was able to display the nav. Thanks! But the only problem is every time I type (input a character) my keyboard dismiss. so i need to click again. Do you know why this is happening by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

you must use the header option instead of headerTitle to define a custom header. even if you want to use headerTitle you have to pass it a function instead of a component
try this

```
setHeader(){
    this.props.navigation.setOptions({
      header: () => <TextInput style={styles.searchInput}/>
    });
  }
```